# Is there an object in Office JS which is equivalent to mytable.tableobject.workbookconnection.oledbconnection.commandtext as per vba

Tags: excel, office-js, office-scripts

Hi I've been advised to try to learn office scripts and am trying to convert an existing vba based solution to office scripts.  The existing solution writes a DAX query and returns an excel table.  I can't find how to access this in typescript.

VBA is

```
Function GetDataFromDataModel(myDAXScript As String) As ListObject
Dim myDaxHubTable As ListObject
Set myDaxHubTable = blwModel.ListObjects("dxtDAXHub")


With myDaxHubTable.TableObject.WorkbookConnection.OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = myDAXScript
        .CommandType = xlCmdDAX
End With
'Debug.Print myDAXScript
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections(myDaxHubTable.TableObject.WorkbookConnection.Name).Refresh
    
   Set GetDataFromDataModel = myDaxHubTable

End Function
```

Comment: So which line gives the error?

Comment: The vba works fine I'm looking for the equivalent in typescript under the excel table object

Comment: I don't believe this operation is currently supported. I don't see any reference to the data model in the API reference. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/overview?view=office-scripts

Comment: Thanks I did have a look through the microsoft site and as they labelled it as something like common classes and can't find the full documentation on their somewhat of a roundabout of links I was asking as it may be something that's uncommon.  Ah well at least when somebody tells me vba is a dead language I can reference this and lack of data model access.

Comment: APIs take time to build. VBA came out 1993. I think Office Scripts only got general availability a few months ago. So there are lots of different features they're working on building.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported today.  In case it helps,  [DataConnectionCollection.refreshAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.dataconnectioncollection?view=excel-js-preview#refreshAll__) is available for existing connections.